# Issues with fopen understanding the filepath I am giving it

Tags: matlab, fopen

Basically, I build a list of files using ls, then want to loop through that list, read in a file, and do some stuff. But when I try to read the file in it fails.

Here is an example

```
r=ls(['Event_2006_334_21_20_11' '/*.r'])

Event_2006_334_21_20_11/IU.OTAV_1.0.i.r
```

which is a 1x80 char

```
fopen(r(1,:))

-1
```

but

```
fopen('Event_2006_334_21_20_11/IU.OTAV_1.0.i.r')

12 (or whatever its on)
```

works. I've tried string(r) and char(r) and sprintf('%s',r). If I just build the string like r = ['Event_2006_334_21_20_11' '/IU.OTAV_1.0.i.r'] it works. So it seems something about combining the different variable types that messes it up but I can't seem to find a workaround. Probably something obvious I'm missing.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried using `dir` instead of `ls`? The structure array returned by `dir` is much more useful for this type of work.

Comment: That does clean my code up a bit. Now I should be able to make the name with... [r(i).folder r(i).name]. It looks right, but still gets the same issue.

Comment: Nevermind, doing that I was just missing a '/', so that the path was incorrect. Now it seems to be working.

Answer (score 1):

ls returns a matrix of characters, which means each row contains the same number of characters. To indicate the problem, try:

```
['-' r(1,:) '-']
```

You will probably notice some whitespaces in front of the `-`. Unless you want to print the output to the command line, ls is not really useful. As mentioned by Alex, use `dir` instead.

A further tip regarding your last comment, concatenate file path using `fullfile`. It makes sure you get one file separator whenever concatenating:

```
>> fullfile('myfolder','mysubfolder','myfile.m')
ans = myfolder/mysubfolder/myfile.m
>> fullfile('myfolder/','mysubfolder','myfile.m')
ans = myfolder/mysubfolder/myfile.m
>> fullfile('myfolder/','/mysubfolder','myfile.m')
ans = myfolder/mysubfolder/myfile.m
```